# Displaying LaTeX in pyQt/pySide QTableWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, latex, pyside

I would like to add mathematical expressions to the table labels (e.g.: 2^3 should be properly formatted)

Here is a simple example of a table:
http://thomas-cokelaer.info/blog/2012/10/pyqt4-example-of-tablewidget-usage/

setHorizontalHeaderLabels accepts string, only. 
I wonder if is it possible to implement somehow this matplotlib approach:
[matplotlib - write TeX on Qt form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2661441/matplotlib-write-tex-on-qt-form?rq=1)

are there other options?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I've also been trying for some time to display complex labels in the header of a *QTableWidget*. I was able to do it by reimplementing the *paintSection* method of a *QHeaderView* and painting manually the label with a *QTextDocument* as described in a [thread on Qt Centre](https://forum.qt.io/topic/30598/solved-how-to-display-subscript-text-in-header-of-qtableview/5).

However, this solution was somewhat limited compared to what could be done with LaTex. I thought this could be a good idea to try the approach you suggested in your OP, i.e. using the capability of matplotlib to render LaTex in PySide.

### 1. Convert matplotlib Figure to QPixmap

First thing that is required in this approach is to be able to convert matplotlib figure in a format that can be easily painted on any *QWidget*. Below is a function that take a [mathTex expression](http://matplotlib.org/users/mathtext.html) as input and convert it through matplotlib to a *QPixmap*.

```
import sys
import matplotlib as mpl
from matplotlib.backends.backend_agg import FigureCanvasAgg
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

def mathTex_to_QPixmap(mathTex, fs):

    #---- set up a mpl figure instance ----

    fig = mpl.figure.Figure()
    fig.patch.set_facecolor('none')
    fig.set_canvas(FigureCanvasAgg(fig))
    renderer = fig.canvas.get_renderer()

    #---- plot the mathTex expression ----

    ax = fig.add_axes([0, 0, 1, 1])
    ax.axis('off')
    ax.patch.set_facecolor('none')
    t = ax.text(0, 0, mathTex, ha='left', va='bottom', fontsize=fs)

    #---- fit figure size to text artist ----

    fwidth, fheight = fig.get_size_inches()
    fig_bbox = fig.get_window_extent(renderer)

    text_bbox = t.get_window_extent(renderer)

    tight_fwidth = text_bbox.width * fwidth / fig_bbox.width
    tight_fheight = text_bbox.height * fheight / fig_bbox.height

    fig.set_size_inches(tight_fwidth, tight_fheight)

    #---- convert mpl figure to QPixmap ----

    buf, size = fig.canvas.print_to_buffer()
    qimage = QtGui.QImage.rgbSwapped(QtGui.QImage(buf, size[0], size[1],
                                                  QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32))
    qpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(qimage)

    return qpixmap
```

### 2. Paint the QPixmaps to the header of a QTableWidget

The next step is to paint the *QPixmap* in the header of a *QTableWidget*. As shown below, I've done it by sub-classing *QTableWidget* and reimplementing the *setHorizontalHeaderLabels* method, which is used to convert the mathTex expressions for the labels into *QPixmap* and to pass it as a list to a subclass of *QHeaderView*. The *QPixmap* are then painted within a reimplementation of the *paintSection* method of *QHeaderView* and the height of the header is set up to fit the height of the mathTex expression in the reimplementation of the *sizeHint* methods.

```
class MyQTableWidget(QtGui.QTableWidget):   
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MyQTableWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setHorizontalHeader(MyHorizHeader(self))

    def setHorizontalHeaderLabels(self, headerLabels, fontsize):

        qpixmaps = []
        indx = 0
        for labels in headerLabels:
            qpixmaps.append(mathTex_to_QPixmap(labels, fontsize))            
            self.setColumnWidth(indx, qpixmaps[indx].size().width() + 16)
            indx += 1

        self.horizontalHeader().qpixmaps = qpixmaps

        super(MyQTableWidget, self).setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headerLabels)


class MyHorizHeader(QtGui.QHeaderView):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(MyHorizHeader, self).__init__(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal, parent)

        self.setClickable(True)
        self.setStretchLastSection(True)

        self.qpixmaps = []

    def paintSection(self, painter, rect, logicalIndex):

        if not rect.isValid():
            return

        #------------------------------ paint section (without the label) ----

        opt = QtGui.QStyleOptionHeader()        
        self.initStyleOption(opt)

        opt.rect = rect
        opt.section = logicalIndex
        opt.text = ""

        #---- mouse over highlight ----

        mouse_pos = self.mapFromGlobal(QtGui.QCursor.pos())               
        if rect.contains(mouse_pos):
            opt.state |= QtGui.QStyle.State_MouseOver

        #---- paint ----

        painter.save()        
        self.style().drawControl(QtGui.QStyle.CE_Header, opt, painter, self)
        painter.restore()

        #------------------------------------------- paint mathText label ----

        qpixmap = self.qpixmaps[logicalIndex]

        #---- centering ----

        xpix = (rect.width() - qpixmap.size().width()) / 2. + rect.x()
        ypix = (rect.height() - qpixmap.size().height()) / 2.

        #---- paint ----

        rect = QtCore.QRect(xpix, ypix, qpixmap.size().width(),
                            qpixmap.size().height())
        painter.drawPixmap(rect, qpixmap)        

    def sizeHint(self):

        baseSize = QtGui.QHeaderView.sizeHint(self)

        baseHeight = baseSize.height()
        if len(self.qpixmaps):
            for pixmap in self.qpixmaps:
               baseHeight = max(pixmap.height() + 8, baseHeight)
        baseSize.setHeight(baseHeight)

        self.parentWidget().repaint()

        return baseSize
```

### 3. Application

Below is an example of a simple application of the above.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)

    w = MyQTableWidget()
    w.verticalHeader().hide()

    headerLabels = [
        '$C_{soil}=(1 - n) C_m + \\theta_w C_w$',
        '$k_{soil}=\\frac{\\sum f_j k_j \\theta_j}{\\sum f_j \\theta_j}$',
        '$\\lambda_{soil}=k_{soil} / C_{soil}$']

    w.setColumnCount(len(headerLabels))
    w.setHorizontalHeaderLabels(headerLabels, 25)        
    w.setRowCount(3)
    w.setAlternatingRowColors(True)

    k = 1
    for j in range(3):
        for i in range(3):
            w.setItem(i, j, QtGui.QTableWidgetItem('Value %i' % (k)))
            k += 1

    w.show() 
    w.resize(700, 200)

    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

which results in:

[image]

The solution is not perfect, but it is a good starting point. I'll update it when I will improve it for my own application.

Comment: @jankos Another option (from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56760843/how-to-display-mathematical-typesetting-mathjax-latex-etc-in-qt-using-pyqt5/56761107#56761107)) is to place a **QWebEngineView** in the table headers and display the equations with MathJax.